# Giving an new index to a table row after deleting other row

Tags: javascript, html

My code is a simple form with 3 input fields. Once the user fills them all in and presses the button it will add a row to the table with the input data aswell as an index number. Like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/NrDdT.jpg

im trying to give each row in a table an index number that is correct with the amount of rows inserted. This works but now I want it to update the index number when I remove one of the rows from the table.

The following function is triggered when the customer fills in an input field with the desired index number that they want to delete and then press a button.

```
    function removeRow() {
        let tabel = document.getElementById("tabel");
        let rows = tabel.getElementsByTagName("tr");
        let indexNumber = document.getElementById("indexnumber").value;

        Object.entries(rows).forEach(([key]) => {
            if(key === indexNumber) {
                tabel.deleteRow(indexNumber);
            }
        })
    }
```

This works and deletes the row that the customer whats but it doesn't update the index numbers for the other rows. So when I delete row 5. My table will look like this.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/czlMN.jpg

I figure I have to loop through all of the rows and set the index to the correct number again. Can anyone help me out :) ?

For the full code check:

https://codepen.io/Botert/pen/bJLLWL

grtz,

Botert

Comment: Make your table data drive instead. Have a data set that represents the table, and every time you mutate the data set, update the view based on its value. So if you wanna remove a row, you would remove an element from your data set then re render the table.

Comment: Could you please explain why you need to do this? Usually data should not rely on in which order ( its index ) it is rendered so there is no hard connection between data and the report that generated the data, which helps when you need to reuse the data later on. If you would actually give the rows a unique id instead of use their index and have the users type the row id, the loop is not needed. Anyways, the new id for each row is the same as the index of the row element inside it's parents children collection, so you can probably use that to update the table cell.

Comment: Right, creating a dictionary with all the rows and is a cleaner/safe approach.

Comment: The problem is im kinda "forced" to use this code ( except for the add and remove index part ) because it is an assignment.
So I cant really change the whole script...that would be fun though.

Sorry if it doesn't make much sense...im just trying to learn how to update it with some cool Javascript tools :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question, try adding the following snippet in your `removeRow()` function:

```
for (var i=1; i<rows.length; i++) {
  var dataRow = rows[i].children[3];
  dataRow.textContent = i;
}
```

Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/ufszamv4/

It's outside of the scope of the question, but consider taking a different approach to the problem. Try placing your rows in an object that has its properties removed. The goal is to simply delete a row without having to update the rest of the data.

Comment: Thanks! It ain't pretty I agree...but it works. I will try to refactor the code aswell for my assignment.